# How to fix this Error: #include <gl/glut.h> "Cannot open source file gl/glut.h"

Tags: c++, opengl, vector, matrix

I was doing some OpenGL programming in C++.

This is part of my code:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include <gl/glu.h>
#include <gl/glut.h> <<< Error here "Cannot open source file gl/glut.h"
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT: I am using Microsoft Visual C++ Express Edition. Sorry forgot to mention it

Comment: You need to install GLUT if I'm not mistaken it isn't included by default in Windows OpenGL

Comment: @JesusRamos How can I install that?

Comment: @Jay http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Is it possible to provide instructions for the installation process or a link? cheers

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You probably haven't installed GLUT:

1. Install GLUT
   If you do not have GLUT installed on your machine you can download it from:
   http://www.xmission.com/~nate/glut/glut-3.7.6-bin.zip (or whatever version)
   GLUT Libraries and header files are
   • glut32.lib
   • glut.h

Source: http://cacs.usc.edu/education/cs596/OGL_Setup.pdf

**EDIT:**

The quickest way is to download the latest header, and compiled DLLs for it, place it in your system32 folder or reference it in your project. Version 3.7 (latest as of this post) is here:
http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/glutdlls37beta.zip

```
Folder references:

glut.h: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\GL\'
glut32.lib: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib\'
glut32.dll: 'C:\Windows\System32\'

For 64-bit machines, you will want to do this.
glut32.dll: 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\'

Same pattern applies to freeglut and GLEW files with the header files in the GL folder, lib in the lib folder, and dll in the System32 (and SysWOW64) folder.
1. Under Visual C++, select Empty Project.
2. Go to Project -> Properties. Select Linker -> Input then add the following to the Additional Dependencies field:
opengl32.lib
glu32.lib
glut32.lib
```

[Reprinted from here](http://visualambition.wordpress.com/2010/08/12/glut-and-visual-studio-2010/)

Comment: Are there any instructions for Microsoft Visual C++ Express Edition

Comment: Updated my post to hopefully give you better instructions re-printed from another site.

Comment: Old but: its not necessary to contaminate the System32 or SysWOW64 folders this way. Just place the header and library files in a folder anywhere on your hard drive and add the folder to the Include Directory and Library Directory of the project. Here is a nice tutorial with some pictures on how to do this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsproject/archive/2009/07/07/vc-directories.aspx

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Visual Studio Community 2015 and trying to Install GLUT you should place the header file `glut.h` in 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\gl`

Answer (score 3):

## Visual Studio Community 2017

Go here :
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10`

and do whatever you were supposed to go in the given directory for **VS 13**.

in the lib folder, you will find some versions, I copied the **32-bit glut.lib** files in **amd** and **x86** and **64-bit glut.lib** in **arm64** and **x64** directories in `um` folder for every version that I could find.

That worked for me.

EDIT : I tried this in windows 10, maybe you need to go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1` folder for **windows 8/8.1**.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find every thing you need:

http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~sugih/courses/eecs487/glut-howto/#win

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `#include <gl/glut.h>` to `#include "gl/glut.h"` in Visual Studio 2013.