# GLUT: Fatal Error: out of memory

Tags: c++, windows, glut

I have an opengl implementation that runs fine on my desktop.
But even though i have it set up the exact same way on my laptop i get an "out of memory" error when i try to run it.

it is strange because on my desktop the application only takes up 200mb ram and i have 2gb available on the laptop

any ideas what might cause this?

btw im running the application through Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and using the glut setup suggested in the first answer of this post: [How to fix this Error: #include <gl/glut.h> "Cannot open source file gl/glut.h"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467473/how-to-fix-this-error-include-gl-glut-h-cannot-open-source-file-gl-glut-h)

Comment: What is the actual error? Is it out of system memory, or is it an error from GL, possibly indicating you are out of graphics memory?

Comment: i was not out of memory, but the error read: "GLUT: Fatal Error: out of memory" so i thought that was the problem.

Comment: Your laptop probably has *much* less graphics memory than your desktop machine.

Comment: that was, as you can see in the accepted post, not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it is rather dumb.

I had set up "main" as "Entry Point" in "Project Preferences -> Linker -> Advanced" because it was necessary on my desktop. 
I removed this so i had a blank "Entry Point" and my code runs fine ^^

posting in case someone needs this info

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the encoding of your file
   (http://lists.apple.com/archives/mac-opengl/2006/Jun/msg00070.html)
2. Ensure you're using the same runtime environment
   (have you installed the same glut.dll on your laptop?)

Finally, I have a question:
What do you mean "running the application through Visual Studio"? Do you hit Ctrl+F5?

Comment: had checked both points out before i found the solution.
and yes i meant hitting Ctrl+F5