# Visual Studio doesn't find GL/glut.h

Tags: c++, opengl, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2017, glut

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 on Windows 10 and I've been trying to install GLUT using [this online guide](http://cacs.usc.edu/education/cs596/OGL_Setup.pdf) that I found on [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467473/how-to-fix-this-error-include-gl-glut-h-cannot-open-source-file-gl-glut-h). However, when I try to compile my code this error still shows up: `fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GL\glut.h': No such file or directory`. I've followed every single step line by line, but nothing seems to work. What could be causing this error?

This is how I'm importing the dependencies:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/GL.h>
#include <GL/GLU.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <cstring>
#include "math.h"
#include <conio.h>
```

Comment: You have to add an C/C++ include path to project properties .

Comment: Make sure that the folder containing GL is in your  `Additional Include Directories`

Comment: ***I've followed every single step line by line*** Those instructions don't seem to be very good.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I have made sure beforehand. It doesn't work

Comment: Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Additional Include Directories. Note the settings exists separately for each combination of platform and configuration.

Comment: Under those settings, I've added this path C:\Users\Dominik\Desktop\OpenGL stuff\headers. Which includes a folder called GL in which glut.h is found. Even Intellisense recognizes it.

Comment: Did you add it to all configurations for your compiler? The settings default to the active configuration.

Comment: You may have to quote this path since there is a space in the path. I always avoid paths with spaces to avoid this issue.

Comment: Yes, I did, it is under all configurations for all platforms.

Comment: I'll try to rename the folder and modify the paths to see whether it works correctly. I've been trying to make this work for like 4 hours straight now.

Comment: If that does not work make sure there is a glut.h file in this GL folder.

Comment: There is, however now I'm starting to see duplicates in Intellisense and there is only one glut.h file in that folder. Interestingly enough it shows files I've removed from the folder.

Comment: `Intellisense` is not always correct. It's geared for speed over accuracy. Trust the compiler over what `Intellisense` suggests.

Comment: I've manually added the full path and the error doesn't show up, however now it doesn't find glut32.lib, funny enough.

Comment: `however now it doesn't find glut32.lib` this is about linker settings. I have no idea why your project is not using your settings correctly. It's hard to debug this way.

Comment: `glut32.lib` maybe you are mixing 32 and 64 bit. Maybe the path is wrong. Maybe `glut32.lib` is corrupt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this, I like to use the Nuget package manager. If you go to

```
Tools>NuGet Package Manager>Package Manager Console
```

Then, in the console type:

```
Install-Package nupengl.core
```

Your problem should be fixed.

Comment: I've done that, but how do I import glut.h from the package manager?

Comment: It imports into your project automatically if you use the NuGet Package Manager.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be the case, all of the glut.h functions turn red in IntelliSense and are undefined in the compiler.

Comment: After running the Install-Package nupengl.core, does it say "Successfully Installed 'nupengl.core...?

Comment: It does. Do I have to add anything to the project properties?

Comment: There shouldn't be. Simply installing the package directly in Visual Studio works for me. I'm not sure why it doesn't work on your end.

Comment: Now I've fixed that problem, however, it doesn't find glut32.lib

Comment: LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'glut32.lib'

Comment: It appears that that library is not included in the nupengl.core package. Maybe try to install it and add it to project dependencies by following the instructions here: http://www.just.edu.jo/~yaser/courses/cs480/opengl/Using%20OpenGL%20and%20GLUT%20in%20Visual%20Studio.htm

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me