# Installing GLUT for openGL windows 8 Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 64 bit

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, glut

Can you please help me install GLUT for windows 8 Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 64 bit? I've tried many tutorials posted and even copied and pasted the dll and header file in said locations.
I keep getting error:

```
Cannot open source file <GL/glut.h>
```

Please recommend any tutorials to be followed so I can get my project working. Thanks in dvance.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/install.php

Comment: Or maybe this will help you: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-setup-opengl-with-visual-studio-2019-on-windows-10/

Comment: @Dershowitz123 I suggest you could refer to the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10467488/11872808